# Is there any way we can directly connect to the function without wanting to click the button i.e., when ever the page loads the function gets called

Tags: html, button, onclick

here is the Html button i want to disable the click function, reducing the extra step so that the function gets called whenever the page gets loded in the browser.

i want to scrape the data(info that comes after clicking the button) from this html file.

OR
Suggest me if we can dirctly call this JS function In Python

I tried Js2Py but cannot translate the Js  File.

i have not tried anything as im not fimailar with html.

i'm supposed to modify the code according to my preferences and im a novoice in html.

i searched in google but couldnt find any relaiable source.

Comment: are you asking how to trigger a function on loading a web page? your question is almost incomprehensible. Any source code you can share?

Comment: <input type="button" id="connect_h" class="bg-info" value="Connect H" onclick="connect('H')" />

Comment: so you want to trigger javascript function named "connect('H')" when loading the page?

Answer (score 0):

the answer is onload function on the Body tag of html instead for onclick it took a while to figure out.

before:

After:

.
.